# Show digits after calculation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calculator

I created a small calculator for getting drip rates. Ive managed to get all the fields to multiply to each other, but it won't multiple digits making some calculations short. Im fairly new to coding and have been trying multiple different options. Can someone help me on this? Here is my code:

import UIKit

class DripCViewController: UIViewController {

//outlets/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@IBOutlet var result: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var volume: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var drip: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var time: UITextField!

@IBAction func solve(sender: UIButton) {
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//math functions/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    if let number1 = Int(volume.text!) {

        if let number2 = Int(drip.text!) {

            if let number3 = Int(time.text!) {

                let firstnumber = number1/number3
                    let secondnumber = firstnumber*number2

                result.text = "\(secondnumber) gtts/min"


            }
        }
    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//keyboard override feature///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    volume .resignFirstResponder();
    drip .resignFirstResponder() ;
    time .resignFirstResponder();
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Float` or `Double` instead of `Int`.

Fixed code:

```
if let number1 = Double(volume.text!) {

    if let number2 = Double(drip.text!) {

        if let number3 = Double(time.text!) {

            let firstnumber = number1/number3
                let secondnumber = firstnumber*number2

            result.text = "\(secondnumber) gtts/min"


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the user input to integers. Those are whole numbers without additional precision (eg so only 1, 2 3 etc and not 1.5 and 2.3) You can use a number type that support numbers with more precision like a double.

Comment: And how would I do that?